# Unit Testing in Angular 5 with Component, Data Source and Service

Tags: angular, jasmine, angular5, karma-jasmine, karma-coverage

I am like a born baby for writing Angular Test cases but trying to learn and I am using Sonar Scanner for checking code coverage.

Am sharing my code, please go have a look:

```
`// test.component.ts 

dataSource: TestDataSource;
..
// method I am trying to test 

loadDataPage() {
      if (this.code === undefined || this.code === 'Test') {
        this.pageNo = this.paginator.pageIndex + 1;
        this.dataSource.loadDatas(
          this.paginator.pageIndex,
          this.paginator.pageSize,
          this.sort.active,
          this.sort.direction,
          this.input.nativeElement.value,
          this.locationSelectedValue,
          this.testticketSelectedValue,
          this.teststatusSelectedValue,
          this.styleOptionSelectedValue
        );
    } else {
      this.getUserByName(this.Name);
    }
  }

...
```

Below is Datasource file:

```
// testDatasource.ts

export class TestDataSource implements DataSource<any> {

..
 loadDatas(pageIndex: number, pageSize: number, sortLabel: string,
        sortDirection: string, search: any, location: string[],
        testticketCount: string[], teststatus: string[], styleOption: string[]) {
        this.loadingSubject.next(true);
        this.testService.getData(pageIndex, pageSize, sortLabel,
            sortDirection, search, location,
             ticketCount, status, styleOption).pipe(catchError(() => of([])), finalize(() => this.loadingSubject.next(false)))
            .subscribe(responses => {
                this.countValue = responses['count'];
                this.dataSubject.next(responses['response']);
            });
    }

..
```

Below is service file:

```
//test.service.ts
export class TestService {
getData(
        pageNumber, pageSize, sortLabel, sortDirection, search,
        location, ticketCount, status, styleOption): Observable<any[]> {
        const object = {
            pageNumber: pageNumber,
            pageSize: pageSize,
            sortLabel: sortLabel,
            sortDirection: sortDirection,
            search: search,
            location: location,
            ticketCount: ticketCount,
            status: status,
            styleOption: styleOption
        };

        return this.apiService.post(this.config.api_url +
            '/testOrder/getall', object).pipe(
                map(res => res)
            );
    }
```

The above there file is my code which I need to test using Karma and Jasmine

The way I tried to test the method am sharing:

```
// test.component.spec.ts

it('should call and run #loaddata()', () => {
    spyOn(comp, 'loadDataPage');
    comp.testcode = 'TEST';
    comp.paginator.pageIndex = 0;
    comp.paginator.pageSize = 25;
    comp.sort.active = null;
    comp.sort.direction = 'desc';
    comp.input.nativeElement.value = null;
    comp.locationSelectedValue = [];
    comp.testticketSelectedValue = [];
    comp.teststatusSelectedValue = [];
    comp.styleOptionSelectedValue = [];

      if (!expect(comp.companycode).toEqual('TEST')) {
        expect(comp.paginator.pageIndex + 1).toBe(1);
        expect(comp.dataSource.loadDatas).toHaveBeenCalledWith(
          comp.paginator.pageIndex,
          comp.paginator.pageSize,
          comp.sort.active,
          comp.sort.direction,
          comp.input.nativeElement.value,
          comp.locationSelectedValue,
          comp.testticketSelectedValue,
          comp.teststatusSelectedValue,
          comp.styleOptionSelectedValue);
    } else {
      expect(comp.paginator.pageIndex + 1).toBe(1);
    }
  });
```

Comment: If you haven't attempted this yourself yet, please do so.  StackOverflow expects you to [try to solve your own problem first](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/261592/how-much-research-effort-is-expected-of-stack-overflow-users), as your attempts help us to better understand what you want. Please edit the question and include your attempted .spec file. For more information, please see [ask] and take the [tour].

Comment: I have attended it and my code I am editing with my test file.

Comment: Are you trying to unit test only the file test.component.ts?  Do you wish to test it in isolation from it's injected service(s)?  I notice you are spying on the component method itself, this will prevent that method from being executed (and tested) which is likely not what you want.   Above all this, it is still not clear to me what you are asking - are you encountering some sort of error?  I suggest you put all the relevant code into a stackblitz to show it in action.  Feel free to fork [this](https://stackblitz.com/edit/stackoverflow-q-53208509?file=app%2Fmy.component.spec.ts) one.